# New xenial install - networking not working

Tags: 16.04, networking

Hoping someone will be able to help me out as I'm scratching my head a bit here.

I've reinstalled xenial on a machine that is to be my virtualisation server. During the installation, it complained that it couldn't contact the DHCP server, so I put the network details in by hand - this machine will have a static IP anyway. Now, though, the interface is showing as down and will not come up. This machine used to work without problems and the network card and switch all show a good link. I've probably done something dumb - it was a slightly hurried late-night install - and now I'm blind to it...

```
root@numbersix:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp37s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:45:cb:64:2b:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.6/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp37s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.66/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary enp37s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c3:56:78 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c3:56:78 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

So, I checked out the state of the networking service:

```
root@numbersix:~# systemctl status networking
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-03-11 20:23:57 GMT; 23s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 1984 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1979 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1984 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix ifup[1984]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix ifup[1984]: Failed to bring up enp37s0.
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And tried a 'start':

```
root@numbersix:~# systemctl start networking
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And then checked journalctl:

```
root@numbersix:~# journalctl -xe
Mar 11 20:23:25 numbersix systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has begun starting up.
Mar 11 20:23:25 numbersix ifup[1934]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mar 11 20:23:25 numbersix ifup[1934]: Failed to bring up enp37s0.
Mar 11 20:23:25 numbersix systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 11 20:23:25 numbersix systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 11 20:23:25 numbersix systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 11 20:23:25 numbersix systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has begun starting up.
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix ifup[1984]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix ifup[1984]: Failed to bring up enp37s0.
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 11 20:23:57 numbersix systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

(I've included the relevant output here, I think)...

I tried bringing the interface up individually:

```
root@numbersix:~# ifup -v enp37s0
Configuring interface enp37s0=enp37s0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave
+ [ inet = meta ]
+ IF_BOND_SLAVES=
+ [  ]
+ [  ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ exit
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
/bin/ip addr add 192.168.1.66/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255       dev enp37s0 label enp37s0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up enp37s0.
```

Then dug around for a bit more info:

```
root@numbersix:~# lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       logical name: enp37s0
       version: 15
       serial: 60:45:cb:64:2b:c8
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe504000-fe504fff memory:fe500000-fe503fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:c3:56:78
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s


root@numbersix:~# lspci -nnk | grep -i A2 net
    25:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:8677]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169


root@numbersix:~# lsmod | grep r8169
r8169                  86016  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
root@numbersix:~# grep r8169 /etc/modprobe/*
root@numbersix:~#
```

Any ideas?

Adam...

Comment: What type of computer is it?  Is the Network disabled in BIOS?  Have you tried a hard power reset on the host by pulling all power from the computer and pressing the power button a couple of times?

Comment: AMD Ryzen 5 1600, B350 mobo, network card Realtek RTL8111H. Networking enabled in BIOS. Yes to hard power reset.

Comment: Try installing the driver:  `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`.  Taken from https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect strongly that Terrance has hit the nail on the head - the xenial installation has selected the r8169 driver over the r8168, and that is causing the problems with the card. I don't understand why the xenial installation did this when the zesty one (upgrading in situ to aardvark) didn't bat an eyelid.

Of course, without a network the process of running a `sudo apt install` is more of a PitA; I played around a little with getting the drivers that I needed loaded to pendrive, but then realised that I had a Centos 7 ISO sitting on my Windows PC. The workload involved in preparing the USB to install that was broadly the same as that involved in getting the packages that I needed to build the correct driver. Centos installed the correct drivers - and everything else, of course - without issues.

I'll probably have another play at some stage, perhaps in KVM...